# Error when trying to list a model inside a model ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to list a model within a model in order to perform a kind of join in the database.
I have two models:

```
public partial class Orders
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
    public string Num_Encomenda { get; set; }
    public string Ref_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Colecao { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
public partial class Colors
{
    public int ID_Programa { get; set; }
    public int ID_Linha_Cor { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to present these two models in my view because I want my order listing to have a table to load in colors associated with my order.
For that I created a new model with the previous models

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Orders> order{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Colors> color{ get; set; }
}
```

and my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var orders= from m in db.Orders
                        select m;
        var cores = from c in db.Colors
                        select c;
        var tables = new OrderViewModel
        {
            order = db.Orders.ToList(),
            color = db.Colors.ToList(),
        };
        return View(orders.ToList());
```

in my view i'm trying to create a table with the orders from inside another table listing the associated colors:

```
@model Balu3._0.ViewModel.OrderViewModel
<table class="table table-borderless table-sm " ;>
@foreach (var Order in Model.order)
{
    <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #cdd0d4;">
        <td style="width: 130px;">
            <b>Artigo: </b>@Order.Cod_Artigo
        </td>
        <td colspan="8">
            <b>Modelo: </b>@Order.Modelo
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
  <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                @foreach (var Color in Model.color)
                {                 
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                            @Color.Color)
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                            <!--Talão-->
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @Html.DropDownList("startServ", "All")
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <textarea name="message" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 }
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and when I run my application I have the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2 [Balu3._0.Models.Program, System.Nullable`1 [System.DateTime]]' , but this dictionary requires a
> model item of type 'Balu3._0.ViewModel.EncomendaViewModel'.

Note: I checked all syntax errors and I believe the problem has nothing to do with it. The code may have syntax errors since I changed some names to better understand my code

Update:for now i just want to list the colors without being associated with the order.

Thanks for the help you can give me!

Comment: You haven't provided the type definition of `EncomendaViewModel` in your question.

Comment: Please add the part of your controller action where you add your data to the view.

Comment: as said the code may have translation errors, thanks for warning. in relation to the controller I added the action

Comment: I am returning the order because it is my main table, the error can be there

Comment: You should be using `return View(tables);`

Comment: that's right, and I complicate it :) since I'm dealing with a large database it crashed, but then I filtered some and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you action to this

`````
public ActionResult Index()
    {
               
        var tables = new OrderViewModel
        {
            order = db.Orders.ToList();
            color = db.Colors.ToList();
        };

return View(tables);

````
`````